# How to improve my database to be more relational - SQL & PHP

Tags: database-design, database-schema, erd

I am making a ordering system using PHP with a database. The database has 2 tables, 1 which holds all of the products, 1 which holds all of the orders made through the php website. 
Products

```
productID (PK)| productName | productPrice
1             | DVD         | 5.99
2             | CD          | 2.99
```

Orders

```
ID (PK) | orderID(PK) | productID(PK/FK) | productName | quantity | ProductPrice
1       | 1           | 1                | DVD         | 1        | 5.99
2       | 1           | 2                | CD          | 2        | 5.98
```

new orders are being inserted into the table using forms that get the data from the Products table and being inserted on submits. Im having a issue that if I was to update the a productName in the Products table, the productName in the Orders table doesnt update.

Also from what I have gathered I also need to implement a OrdersProducts table like this

```
orderID | productID
```

What would I need to do so that each time a order is made, the orderID and productID go into this table?

Comment: After insert trigger is what you are looking for

Comment: @sagi so after insert orderid productid into ordersProducts? Something like that?

Comment: You can read here: http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php or here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: "Im having a issue..." what is the issue? That would be better to start with an [ERD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) to end up with a better solution while designing databases like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Products:

```
productID (PK)| productName | productPrice
1             | DVD         | 5.99
2             | CD          | 2.99
```

Line Items:

```
ID (PK) | orderID(FK) | productName | quantity | productPrice
1       | 1           | DVD         | 1        | 5.99
2       | 1           | CD          | 2        | 5.98
```

Orders:

```
ID (PK) | some other fields - maybe some order time details?
1       | some other data
```

You don't need an additional table, unless you need to store extra information about the order. Your "Orders" table is more or less a "Line Items" table. It's normal for this to include copies of the product name and price at time of purchase so you can go back and look.

You can use what's called a "trigger" to insert into tables after every action, which is described in the [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).

However what I'd recommend doing instead is using a transaction to turn a multiple commands into a single atomic insert

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO Orders (ID, someotherfields) VALUES (1, etc); 
INSERT INTO LineItems (ID, orderID, productName, quantity, productPrice) VALUES (1, 1, "DVD","5.99");
COMMIT;
```

The reason is that you probably can't automatically determine what you'll want to insert automatically into the orders table on insert to the line items table.

Comment: Thank you @BillieThompson this has been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

your design missing somethings:

firstly: your order table should contain only `order_id`, `order_date`, and customer data like `customer_id`

secondly: you must do the one `OrdersProducts` table because your order may have a lot of one product and also you should put these fields in it: `orderID`, `productID`, `quantity`, `ProductPrice` but you shouldn't put `productName` in this table, you refere the product by its id only. also you can remove `ProductPrice` from this table and consider this price in `Products` table, but you may need this field if your product price changed for each customer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @GoudaElalfy